# Ubuntu 13.04 server cant install centrifydc apt package E: Unable to locate package centrifydc

Tags: 13.04, command-line, server, apt

I get an unable to locate package error when i try to install centrifydc using apt-get.

Steps taken:

I sudo nano'd /etc/apt/sources.list and uncommented the two partner urls.
Then i performed a sudo apt-get update.
Then i performed a sudo apt-get install centrifydc.

...stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `centrifydc` package is not anymore available in repositories starting with Ubuntu 12.10. It is only available in 12.04.

You can try to install manually from here (it's a [.tar.gz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) file):

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/centrifydc/5.1.1-831-0ubuntu1
```

but I can not guarantee it will work in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Thanks, i thought i was going mad.  Do you know any reason why it was removed? Performance, stability, security?

Comment: There are proprietary closed source DEB packages upstream for 13.04 here: http://www.centrify.com/express/free-active-directory-tools-for-linux-mac.asp#agents - download requires registration.